# Calculation error with Numbers containing more than 3 Digits

Tags: php

I'm importing prices from a database using the following code:

```
//implode items, turn into string
$item_implode = join("','", $item_array);

//declare an overall array for result
$product = array();

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name, WPrice as price, APrice as a_price from my_table where Name IN ('$item_implode') ORDER BY FIELD (Name, '$item_implode');");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $product_name = $row['Name'];
    // find all keys in $item_array which value is the products
        $keys = array_keys($item_array, $product_name);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {

        // add values for these keys
        $product[$key + 1]["Name"] = $row['Name'];
        $product[$key + 1]["price"] = number_format($row['price'],2);
        $product[$key + 1]["a_price"] = number_format($row['a_price'],2);
    }
}
```

And then I apply the following functions:

```
function price($m) {

global $product,$i; 

  if ($m == "a") {
    $value =  $product[$i]["a_price"];
  } 

  else { 
    $value = $product[$i]["price"]; //
  }

  return $value;

}
```

I'm trying to use the following comparison:

```
<?php if ( price( a )< price( default ) ) {echo "Smaller";} ?>
```

To echo `Smaller` whenever the price of A is smaller than the default price.

It works fine for prices in the range of `0` to `999.99`, but for when a price of `1,000` or more is involved, I'm getting the opposite results (it echos smaller when bigger and vice-versa)

What is causing this problem?

Comment: Numbers don't have commas in them, numbers are just digits with or without a decimal point.... remove the comma (`,`) from your "number" and things will magically work

Comment: But I don't want to remove the comma. I want to display those prices with commas. How can I do both?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use the comma in a display; but you cannot use it in a comparison and expect a match... that means you're trying to compare formatted strings, not numbers

Comment: remove your comma and use `preg_replace` or `sprint_f` to output them in the format you want, else you need to use to strip the comma and assign the result to a new variable before using it with comparison operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing strings because that's what you stored in `$product["price"]` and `$product["a_price"]` (the function `number_format()` returns a string value). For numbers `>= 1000`, those strings include commas, which breaks the comparison.

Compare the numeric values and don't call `number_format()` until you need to display the values.